# PHP cURL issues...error 401

Tags: php, curl

I making a port of a functionality from a working C# class to a PHP class
I'm tryinhg to do a very simple task but the performance is different and I can't find the problem, maybe you guys can help.

This is the C# code (not mine, working as is, sensitive data hidden):

```
        Stream requestStream = null;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        StringBuilder postBuilder = null;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
        string requestUrl = null;
        string cookieString = null;
        byte[] rawPostData = null;

        requestUrl = "https://some_server/Login";
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        postBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        postBuilder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>");
        postBuilder.Append("<authorization>");
        postBuilder.Append("<username><![CDATA[some_name]]></username>");
        postBuilder.Append("<password><![CDATA[some_password]]></password>");
        postBuilder.Append("<domain><![CDATA[some_domain]]></domain>");
        postBuilder.Append("</authorization>");

        rawPostData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postBuilder.ToString());

        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Accept = "*/*,text/xml";
        webRequest.ContentLength = rawPostData.Length;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "dsaxess/special";

        requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(rawPostData, 0, rawPostData.Length);
        requestStream.Flush();


        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Debug.WriteLine("Status: " + webResponse.StatusCode);
        //Debug.Write(webRequest.Headers);
        //Debug.Write(webResponse.Headers);
        requestStream.Close();
        requestStream = null;
        postBuilder = null;

        Debug.WriteLine("Done!");
```

This is my PHP Code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "https://some_server/Login";
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    //$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

    $xml_data = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>".
                "<authorization>".
                "<username><![CDATA[some_name]]></username>".
                "<password><![CDATA[some_password]]></password>".
                "<domain><![CDATA[some_domain]]></domain>".
                "</authorization>";

    $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml",
            "Accept: */*,text/xml",
            "User-Agent: dsaxess/special",
            "Host: ".$host,
            "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data),
            "Expect: 100-continue",
            "Connection: Keep-Alive"
    );

    //var_dump($headers);
    //var_dump($xml_data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
        //var_dump($data);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

C# Code give Status OK and a valid authentication token.
PHP Code give Status 401 and error: User does not exist.

I can't tell why is different. 
I compared the request and response header on both and everything look the same.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself. Headers syntax was wrong. The correct syntax is:

```
$headers = array(
            "Content-type" => "text/xml",
            "Accept" => "*/*,text/xml",
            "User-Agent" => "dsaxess/special",
            "Host" => $host,
            "Content-length" => strlen($xml_data),
            "Expect" => "100-continue",
            "Connection" => "Keep-Alive"
    );
```